# iOS Set CAGradientLayer under UIButton with image

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

in my iOS app i have a problem, have a button with image, i would to set a gradient to button under image, i write this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [GradientColor btnGreyGradient];
    [gradient setFrame:self.btnTicketView.layer.bounds];
    gradient.masksToBounds = YES;

   [self.btnTicketView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    self.btnTicketView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

and my GradientColor class is:

```
 #import "GradientColor.h"

@implementation GradientColor


+(CAGradientLayer *)btnGreyGradient
{


    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:169.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:169.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];


    NSArray *arrayColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id) startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor, nil];


    CAGradientLayer *viewGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
viewGradient.colors = arrayColors;

    return viewGradient;

}
```

The problem is the when i set the gradient to my button, the image that i had set into InterfaceBuilder is covered. 
how can i resolve this problem??
Thank You

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what you want the behavior to be; is the image on the button opaque?  If so, how do you expect to get a gradient layer to even be visible?  If not, do you want the gradient to appear behind any transparency you have in the button's image?

Comment: I can tell you that, based on what you have here, the effect that you describe is exactly what I would expect:  you're putting the gradient layer, with no transparency (alpha = 1 means opaque), as the top layer, so it's going to hide everything beneath it, exactly the same way that putting an opaque image on top of anything else will hide everything beneath it.  You'll need to set the gradient layer *behind* the image layer, so you'll need to tweak the index you're using in the call to `-insertSublayer:atIndex:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bring the imageView to top after you insert the layer.

```
[self.btnTicketView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[self.btnTicketView bringSubviewToFront:self.btnTicketView.imageView];
```

Edited:

You might want to create your subclass of button, so that can be reuse, something like:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self myInit];
    }
    return self;
}

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self myInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self myInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) myInit
{
    _gradientLayer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    _gradientLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;

    NSArray* locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@0, @0.40, @0.60, @1, nil];

    [_gradientLayer setLocations:locations];

    [self.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];

    NSArray* colors = [self getGradientColors];

    [_gradientLayer setColors:colors];
}
```

Comment: Thank you....It's work well.Please can you tell me how can i use gradient for more equals size Buttons??

Comment: See the edited, you can create a subclass of UIButton, so that you can reuse it.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. But on iPhone 6s emulator,why gradient doesn't  coverage all button?

Comment: Could you show me how you define the button subClass and how you use it?

Comment: I don't use a subclass on UIButton because i'm new on iOS and object c and i don't understand how i can use it. I used the first code that you wrote, it's works for small screen but not for big. Sorry for my bad english. Thank you

Comment: Could you share your code and I can try find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientTicket = [GradientColor btnGreyGradient];
[gradientTicket setFrame:self.btnTicketView.layer.bounds];
gradientTicket.masksToBounds = YES;

[self.btnTicketView.layer insertSublayer:gradientTicket atIndex:0];
[self.btnTicketView bringSubviewToFront:self.btnTicketView.imageView];
[self.btnTicketView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[self.btnTicketView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/255.0 green:221/255.0 blue:221/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
self.btnTicketView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Where GradientColor is the class that i wrote before. 
This is what happens on iPhone 6s:

[image]

but on iPhone 5s it's ok:

[image]

I have another question, can you tell me why i can't use the same gradient object for more buttons?? If i do that, gradient appears only on the last button.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You call this in viewDidLoad, in that moment AutoLayout doesn't effect yet.  And My guess you are showing the viewController as iPhone5 size in storyboard, so it looks wierd on iPhone6.  Try move the call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Seriously, you should define your own UIButton subclass.

Comment: If i use viewDidLayoutSubviews it's work perfectly. I try to use your UIButton subclass but i have the same problem. Can you tell me why i should create four different gradient layers for buttons, because if i use the same gradient object it doesn't work for all four buttons. Thank you, you're very helpfull

Comment: I guess you have to ask Apple why one gradientLayer instance cannot be used by multiple UIView.  For now, you have to create a new gradientLayer instance for each button.